# OPC UA: How open a server file for write raw data in OPC UA?

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm creating a C# application that sends a file to a Siemens numeric control, using OPC UA.

I'm using the `CopyFileToServer` method. The file is created but I have seen that to pass the raw data in the file, you must use the `Open` method contained in filetype, pass the raw data and call the `Close` method to close the file.
I tried several times to use the `Open` method without having succeeded.
Can someone help me?

I tried it in Windows 10 64 bit computer with Visual Studio 2017.

```
public void SendFile(Opc.Ua.Client.Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            if (session != null)
            {

                NodeId node0 = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods");
                NodeId node1 = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/GiveUserAccess");
                object[] argument0 = new object[2];

                argument0[0] = "USER";
                argument0[1] = "SinuWriteAll";

                session.Call(node0, node1, argument0);

                NodeId node = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods");
                NodeId method = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/CopyFileToServer");
                object[] argument = new object[3];
                byte[] data = new byte[1];

                argument[0] = "Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program/sendFile.mpf";
                argument[1] = data;
                argument[2] = true;

                var a = session.Call(node, method, argument);

                NodeId nodeFile = new NodeId("file to open"); // The problem is this (i don't find the method for the file server nodeid)
                NodeId methodOpen = new NodeId("ns=0;i=11580");
                object[] argument1 = new object[1];
                argument1[0] = OpenFileMode.Write;

                var hndl = session.Call(nodeFile, methodOpen, argument1); // Exception 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

The code above returns the following exception:

> "Bad invalid argument".

Comment: Could you please add to your post which OPC UA libraries, framework or sdk you are using?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.1, DLL OPC UA (OPC UA Foundation) Ver 1.3.352.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
    NodeId open = new NodeId("ns=2;s=Sinumerik/FileSystem/Part Program/SENDFILE.MPF.Open");
    var parent = GetMethodParent(session, open);
    object[] argument1 = new object[1];
    argument1[0] = Convert.ToByte(OpenFileMode.Write);
    var hndl = session.Call(parent, open, argument1);
```

In this way I have the handle to use with the write function.
In NodeId "Open" is indicated the file to open.

The function "GetMethodParent":

```
private NodeId GetMethodParent(Session session, NodeId methodNodeId)
    {
        session.Browse(
          null,
          null,
          methodNodeId,
          0u,
          BrowseDirection.Inverse, //browse in inverse direction
          ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences,
          true,
          (uint)NodeClass.Object, //only return nodes of type Object
          out _,
          out var references); //get all parent references

        var parentReference = references[0]; //a MethodNode can only have one parent reference
        return ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(parentReference.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris); //return the NodeId converted from an ExpandedNodeId
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An important thing, it is use Browse method after create a new NodeId. The Browse method, permit to of reload the tree of the server with the new NodeID just created.

```
     private ReferenceDescriptionCollection Browse(Session session, BrowseDescription nodeToBrowse, bool throwOnError)
    {
        try
        {
            var descriptionCollection = new ReferenceDescriptionCollection();
            var nodesToBrowse = new BrowseDescriptionCollection { nodeToBrowse };
            BrowseResultCollection results;
            DiagnosticInfoCollection diagnosticInfos;
            session.Browse(null, null, 0U, nodesToBrowse, out results, out diagnosticInfos);
            ClientBase.ValidateResponse(results, nodesToBrowse);
            ClientBase.ValidateDiagnosticInfos(diagnosticInfos, nodesToBrowse);
            while (!StatusCode.IsBad(results[0].StatusCode))
            {
                for (var index = 0; index < results[0].References.Count; ++index)
                    descriptionCollection.Add(results[0].References[index]);
                if (results[0].References.Count == 0 || results[0].ContinuationPoint == null)
                    return descriptionCollection;
                var continuationPoints = new ByteStringCollection();
                continuationPoints.Add(results[0].ContinuationPoint);
                session.BrowseNext(null, false, continuationPoints, out results, out diagnosticInfos);
                ClientBase.ValidateResponse(results, continuationPoints);
                ClientBase.ValidateDiagnosticInfos(diagnosticInfos, continuationPoints);
            }
            throw new ServiceResultException(results[0].StatusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (throwOnError)
                throw new ServiceResultException(ex, 2147549184U);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```